# Its showing some error at By.xpath i.e., the method xpath is undefined for the method BY

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class LaunchBrowser_TestNG {

 
    @Test
      public void LaunchBrowser() throws InterruptedException{
        
        
        

        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true); 
        caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "/projects/challenge/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs");
        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
        System.out.println("PhantomJS Headless Driver launched");
        
        // Write your script here
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println ("Launch Browser is successful");
    System.out.println("Page Title : " + driver.getTitle());
          
    

        //Searching for "Fresco Play" in Google search
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='gLFyf gsfi']")).sendKeys("Fresco Play");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='gLFyf gsfi']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Page Title : " + driver.getTitle());
                    
    }
}
```

There is some error at By.xpath. It says -

> the method xpath is undefined for the method BY.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to import `import org.openqa.selenium.By` on top of your test.
and then like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath,value= "//input[@class='gLFyf gsfi']")).sendKeys("Fresco Play");
```

Try this if the above code is not working:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@class='gLFyf gsfi']")
```

Comment: The above question pertains to Java bindings. The solution that you have given is for Python bindings. Please specify in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a required import is missing. You need to add:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```